# Intersection of Sets in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, hashmap, set

I have a `HashMap` of the following form in Scala:

```
HashMap(
37 -> HashSet(5, 1, 6, 9, 13, 12, 3, 8, 4),
20 -> HashSet(5, 1, 6, 9, 13, 12, 3, 8, 4), 
45 -> HashSet(5, 6, 9, 13, 3, 8, 4), 
49 -> HashSet(5, 6, 9, 13, 3, 8, 4), 
39 -> Set(5, 12, 3, 9), 
31 -> HashSet(5, 6, 9, 13, 3, 8, 4),
15 -> Set(5, 9, 3), 
28 -> Set(5, 3, 9), 
21 -> HashSet(5, 6, 9, 13, 3, 8, 4), 
33 -> Set(9, 3), 
40 -> HashSet(5, 1, 6, 9, 13, 12, 3, 8, 4), 
26 -> Set(9, 3, 5), 
55 -> Set(6, 4, 8),
23 -> Set(9, 5, 3, 12), 
36 -> Set(7, 2), 
19 -> Set(5, 9, 3))
```

What is the most efficient way to get the intersection of all Sets in the Map?

The problem is that these map and sets might grow large and the intersection is needed abundantly in a recursive algorithm (up to 10K calls in one execution) and the `For comprehension` in Scala is not doing the trick efficiently.

Edit :

As for `For comprehension` I just did a simple function to compute it (it has one non useful intersection that could be optimized, the first one, irrelevant to the high number of calls. I could also stop the computation once the intersection is empty but it rarely happens but I am avoiding the intersection of empty values since theoretically in my algorithm, the Map should not have keys with empty values :

```
def stateIntersection(m: Map[Int, Set[Int]]): Set[Int] = {
    var acc = m.head._2
    for ((k, v) <- m) {
      if (v.nonEmpty)
        acc = acc.intersect(v)
    }
    acc
  }
```

Comment: What did you try with for-comprehension that is not efficient?

Comment: `.values.reduce(_ intersect _)`? (Warning: won't work on an empty `Map`.)

Comment: To the above I would just add that if you need to intersect tons of sets of numbers, perhaps, something like `BitSet` could be more effective than random `Set` implementations.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, Thank you, I will look up into the data structures/types  and see if I can redo the construction of the original map with `Bitset`

Comment: @jwvh It seems to compute it correctly and more efficiently. I will make sure not to call my function on an empty `Map`

Comment: It seems that the time complexity in your implementation is O(MN) where M is number of keys in the map and N is number of values in a Set. If M ~ N, you get O(N^2) and this is considered inefficient. The `reduce` approach has the same time complexity. If you calculate `stateIntersection` frequently on the same `Map[Int, Set[Int]]`, try memoizing it

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Noted. But I am not sure then why the reduce approach led in practise to a much faster execution time.

Comment: Probably `.values.reduce` gave you the speed up by a constant factor. You don't have to do pattern matching to extract keys from tuple (`.values`). Also you're not intersecting head against itself and aren't filtering out empty sets (`.reduce`).

Answer (score 0):

Do the values in your sets have lower and upper bounds? In case they do, and the range is reasonably small (say, 0..1000), an efficient way (in any language) could be to create a fixed size array int[0..1000], then iterate over all sets and increment the corresponding array element. This is a constant time operation unlike searching in a set, which would be inevitably part of the algorithm above.

```
counters = int[1000] // assuming it's initialized with 0's
for set in sets {
  for element in set.elements {
    counters[element]++
  }
}
```

Then you simply collect the array elements with the values equal to the number of sets.